# Intersection quick failure for Java2D

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, java-2d

I'm trying to come up with a fast iterative/recursive process for telling when a java2D path does NOT intersect any other java2D objects. In other words, I would like to come up with a "quick failure" algorithm for intersection based solely on the rect bounds of these java2D paths. Here is an example screenshot:

[image]

In this screenshot you see all kinds of circles, where some of the circles overlap (the chain on the left hand side).

My main reason for asking this question is that I'm looking to improve the algorithm I have for combining (or merging) all objects that overlap.
In the example above, after I merged all objects in this picture it would look like this:

[image]

Here is what I've tried thus far:

1. A double reverse while loop, where for each iteration I test whether the two objects intersect (using Java's Area.intersect(Area)) and if so, create the merged object, add it to the list of objects and remove the two objects that were merged together and continue. Unfortunately, for many objects (as is the case in the screenshot) this algorithm tends to be very slow.
2. A preprocessing step where again I use a double loop to try and sift out those objects which have no chance of intersection based solely on comparing rect bounds. The individual calculation to compare rect bounds is fast, however, I still have to test every object against every other object to be sure it has no intersections. Hence, again I have a quadratic time algorithm.
3. A recursive method where it does a greedy search for intersection. So at object A, if you find an intersecting object B, recurse on object B to find all its intersecting objects, and so on. This finds me all chains of intersecting objects, which afterwards I could throw out all chains of size 1 and only merge the remaining chains. However, at each step of the recursion you still have to check against all other objects other than the ones in the chain that lead you to the current object, so it still seems to have potential to be slow in my estimation. The one benefit is that once you've visited a branch, all objects in that branch have been determined to have intersection and what they intersected, so there is no need to check these objects when continuing down another branch.

Any suggestions/comments/links to better algorithms for this sort of thing would be greatly beneficial to me.  Thanks!

Comment: (There may be similar and maybe even duplicate questions - one should check this). A detailed answer would be long. The key issue seems to be that you have a running time of `O(n*n)` for checking each object for intersections with each other. A classical solution for that is *Spatial Hashing*. This sorts objects into a 2D grid, with hash-based lookup, where you can determine the intersections of *one* object in `O(1)` (a bit simplified here). I found https://conkerjo.wordpress.com/2009/06/13/spatial-hashing-implementation-for-fast-2d-collisions/ gives a nice overview

Comment: Thanks for the article reference Marco. Appears to be exactly what I need. Cheers!